# -1073741811(0xc000000d) error opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, error-handling, runtime-error

I installed OpenCV version 2.4.3 using Visual Sudio 10 as the IDE (on windows 7 64-bit). 
The problem is that once I installed it and am running even a simple application like that of loading an image it is giving me an error

`The program '[8120] pms1.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741811 (0xc000000d)`

I am getting the same error for any code that I am trying to run. I am not getting any build errors. Build is getting succeeded but when I run it it throws me this.

Note: a sample code which gave me the error

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat image;

  VideoCapture cap;
  cap.open(0);

  namedWindow(“window”, 1);

  while(1) {
    cap>>image;

    imshow(“window”, image);
    waitKey(33);
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same results when main() is empty?

Comment: @ParkerKemp no. I just did that and it didn't give me that error. The Command prompt opened and closed automatically

Comment: So clearly it's something in your code, not external. You need to do some debugging to narrow it down. Try adding back the code a piece at a time to figure out which line is causing issues (I know nothing about OpenCV, so I'm just giving you some basic tips).

Comment: @ParkerKemp I did like you said and tried to figure out line at at time. And apparently the first line of code "Mat image" itself is giving the error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your executable and the opencv dll files it calls are both 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: The executable is 32-bit. And it is calling kernel32.dll, msvcr100d.dll and opencv_core243d.dll and some other (opencv_xxxd.dll)files. The _opencv_ _ ones are present in both x86 and x64 bit folders. So I think both the executable and the dll files both are of the same type i.e. 32-bit. 

So can you please help further

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the capture interface failed to open device `0`, so `cap>>image;` is probably causing the error. You just don't know it because you forgot to check the success of `open()`:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
     // print error message and 
     // quit the application
}
```

Experiment to pass other values for `open()`, like -1 or 2.

Comment: I tried executing it line by line commenting the rest. It gave error in the first line Mat image itself.

Comment: Use [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to check that you have all the DLLs needed to execute the application.